# Uncaught ReferenceError when passing values through onchange event

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to understand why I get an Uncaught ReferenceError when using the randomURL function. page1.php creates it, passes it onto page2.php, then passes it onto page3.php. When I make a selection and kick off the onchange event nothing happens.
Any suggestions or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

page1.php

```
<?php

$mycode = randomURL();

$url = '/page2.php?code='.$mycode;
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">'; 

?>

function randomURL() {
    $alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $pass = array();
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    return implode($pass);
}
```

when randomURL is run it creates a code like d4KLzmXt24EeoOB and places it in the url.

page3.php code is:

```
<?php
    $mycode = $_GET['code'];

    <select name="bookings" onchange="showbookings(this.value,'.$mycode.')">
        <option value="">Select Booking Types To See:</option>
        <option value="1">All Booking</option>
        <option value="2">Open Bookings</option>
        <option value="3">Closed Bookings</option>
    </select>
?>
```

when page3.php is run here is the page source result:

```
    <select name="bookings" onchange="showbookings(this.value,d4KLzmXt24EeoOB)">
        <option value="">Select Booking Types To See:</option>
        <option value="1">All Booking</option>
        <option value="2">Open Bookings</option>
        <option value="3">Closed Bookings</option>
    </select>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: d4KLzmXt24EeoOB is not defined

```
function showbookings(str, pass) {
    if (str === "") {
        document.getElementById("txtBookings").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enclose your strings between apostrophes or quotes. The apostrophes you are showing in the incomplete part of php you have here:

```
<select name="bookings" onchange="showbookings(this.value,'.$mycode.')">
```

Are for concatenating some strings. But you have none as delimiters in the js code. So that might be something like:

```
<select name="bookings" onchange="showbookings(this.value,\''.$mycode.'\')">
```

Comment: mishu - thanks. I thought I tried that yesterday. I appreciate your response back.  Kurt